# How to toggle High Contrast mode in VB.Net for all elements?

Tags: vb.net, high-contrast

Is there anyway of having a button (btnHCon) clicked event in which enables high contrast mode in vb.net (and then obviously one in which turns it off again)?

I am looking to add the functionality/accessibility in adding this to my project (similar to toggling High contrast in Control Panel)?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: High Contrast mode? Do you want an image in `picturebox` to be high contrasted?

Comment: I want the whole form in high contrast, including all images/buttons/ etc as they would appear if high contrast is enabled on the PC itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the only way to do this is to use the system default colors for your forms / controls when in high contrast mode (since only those will be changed by high contrast mode).[<sup>1</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb35a5fw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  To turn on high contrast mode, it seems your only option is to use unmanaged code--particularly, [`SystemParametersInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `uiAction` `SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST` with a [`HIGHCONTRAST` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  for `pvParam`.

I'm not very good at making calls to unmanaged code but thankfully [chris128 at VBForums has done the hard work](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?577156-Turn-On-High-Contrast).  You're on your own for setting it back though!  But I think if you look at the references above you can figure out the appropriate tweaks.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
'
'API declarations
'

Public Const HCF_HIGHCONTRASTON As Integer = 1
Public Const SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST As Integer = 67
Public Const SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE As Integer = 2

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure HIGHCONTRAST
    Public cbSize As UInteger
    Public dwFlags As UInteger
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
    Public lpszDefaultScheme As String
End Structure

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SystemParametersInfoW")> _
Public Shared Function SystemParametersInfoW(ByVal uiAction As UInteger, ByVal uiParam As UInteger, ByVal pvParam As System.IntPtr, ByVal fWinIni As UInteger) As <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function

'
'End of API declarations
'

'Some button click event
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim highcontraststruct As New HIGHCONTRAST
    highcontraststruct.dwFlags = HCF_HIGHCONTRASTON
    highcontraststruct.cbSize = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(highcontraststruct))
    Dim highcontrastptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(highcontraststruct))
    Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(highcontraststruct, highcontrastptr, False)

    SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETHIGHCONTRAST, CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(highcontraststruct)), highcontrastptr, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)

End Sub
End Class
```